# SP13: Changing Subsite Title

Tags: 2013, javascript, master-page, url, sub-site

I have seen many posts how to change subsite title but still confused. I know that this is very simple, but when I change the title it also changes the url.  I do not want it to change the url just the title like a document library.  can someone please help me figure the steps to change a subsite title without changing the subsite url?  Thank you for the help.

Comment: what's the template of your subsite? changing site title is so simple : site setting > look and feel > click on Title, description, and logo , change title it should not change the url !

Comment: @M,Qassas Its a team site.

Comment: I have created a subsite from team site especially for you :)  to try your scenario, I changed the title as I mentioned above and there is no effect on reflected URL?!! could you please mention your steps?

Comment: M.Qassas is right there shouldn't be any effect on the url. I am now also curious about the exact steps. :)

Comment: Here are my steps. Page Library > View All Pages > Edit Properties.  Thank you for your help

Comment: So it is not a subsite you are changing, it is a page. For pages, have a look at this : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Work-with-pages-in-a-publishing-site-363d1381-b5a5-4edc-a760-e8822acafbef?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US